# remove almost-duplicates containing substring of next line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, uniq

I need to know a way to remove duplicate strings in line, but let me explain, cause I have already used `uniq`. In a file, I get these two lines:

```
ANASI:A=4-63261950;
ANASI:A=4-63261950,ES=541;
```

The string `4-63261950` is duplicated in both lines, but the line itself is different, only that string is equal in both lines. I just need a way to process the entire file and remove the first line and leave only the one with the `ANASI:A=4-63261950,ES=541;`. The file will contain several lines with this exact same scenario. Is there a way to do this with `sed` or something?

Comment: Maybe if you manage to express the match criteria more clearly?  Is this the entire line, will the "extra data" always be ,ES=something; ?

Answer (score 4):

awk to the rescue...

assuming your delimiters and structure stays the same

```
sort file | awk -F"[;,]" '!a[$1]++'
```

will pick the first one based on lexical order (`,` < `;`)

Comment: But this would change the order of the file

Comment: sorting is implied by use of `uniq` in the description.

Comment: Just wanted to make the OP aware of that ;)

Comment: @karakfa: Please add output with Jaime Castelltort's two lines.

Comment: OP is not clear about this but this code keep only 1 occurence per "root" string, if there are  2 extension, only the first is catch. We can assume it's ok, so nice code using the sort (`;` before `,`) perfectly

Comment: Well, yes, it worked, and I do appreciate that.  Where I can find a good awk tutorial?  I have seen that awk solves almost anything related to file processing, so it is time to start learning it.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: this 1995 dated manual looks pretty decent http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawkA4.pdf

Comment: Also, at the end I was doing this to the file:
sort file | uniq > $2 

So, since you are already doing the sort, I just added the awk, so my 
sort file | uniq | awk -F"[;,]" '!a[$1]++' > $2

And it seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If file is huge (and memory a problem or issue)

```
sort YourFile | awk -F '[;,]' 'Last != $1{print}{Last = $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 'N;/^(.*);\n\1,/!P;D' file
```

This uses a moving window to compare successive pairs of lines to print the required match.